# no implicit conversion to float from nil

Tags: ruby, rmagick

why i always got this error

```
@Font_Size=params['FontSize'].to_i
img.annotate(txt,0,0,@XDIM[xLoop].to_i,@YDIM[xLoop].to_i,@Trans[xLoop]){
txt.gravity=Magick::SouthGravity
txt.pointsize=@Font_Size         <<<<######### The Error Line
txt.stroke='#000000'
txt.fill='#ff0000'
txt.font_weight=Magick::BoldWeight
}
```

why always got the error  `no implicit conversion to float from nil`
i'm tried to covert the size to int but still get this error

Comment: I guess `#pointsize=` is complex method, in which thr code tri to implicitly convert a value to float. what is the `@Font_Size` value?

Comment: i tried to convert it to Float but still get the same error 
????

Comment: have you tried to assign a float to `pointsize`?

Comment: 1. Can you insert `p params['FontSize']; p @Font_Size` after the 1st line and copy&paste the output?  2. What do you get when you replace `txt.pointsize=@Font_Size` with `txt.pointsize=12.0` ?

Comment: its work well if i set it with my hand like 'txt.pointsize=12' that
but the problem appear to me when it take the value from variable

Comment: also when i tried to assign a float i got the same error 
so how i can solve this issue ?

Comment: @Astm di you follow nodakai's first suggestion?

Comment: yes but still got the same error

Comment: @Astm: Go ahead and do what nodakai said and copy and paste the output of `@Font_Size=params['FontSize'].to_i;p params['FontSize']; p @Font_Size;` to a comment here and we can be more help. It looks like the `FontSize` parameter does not exist in the `params` array.